# How can I create a text file to a folder location as a operating system file?

Tags: excel, vba

I want to create a text file as a operating system file using vba code? Is this possible? Reason I want to do this is so that the regular user cannot see the text file. I know there's the save file as hidden feature but i don't want to use that. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What are you trying to archive with the hidden file? Will the other users need access to the file when they run a macro?

Comment: @VBAPete No, they don't need access to this file. Reason for is, i want to save a file from within the excel file that will save a property to it since my excel workbook will be password protected therefore, I cannot access the properties of that workbook. Then i will have another application that will access these text file for the properties ect.

Comment: If you *really* don't want a regular user to find it, take a look at [alternate data streams](http://vb.mvps.org/samples/Streams/).

Comment: @Comintern I really don't want to have to create two files, a text file and a ads file. I just want to create a text file from excel that stores some values to access by another application for value usage ect.

Comment: I meant create an ADS for the workbook itself *instead of* a text file.

Comment: I'm open for other options. Thanks though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with the `Scripting.FileSystemObject`:

```
'Requires reference to Microsoft Scripting Runtime
Sub SetSystemHiddenAttribs(filepath As String)
    With New Scripting.FileSystemObject
        With .GetFile(filepath)
            .Attributes = .Attributes Or Hidden Or System
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a way to do this in pure VBA, but you can create your text file then pass the [`attrib`](http://ss64.com/nt/attrib.html) command to shell. eg:

```
Shell "ATTRIB +S +H MyHiddenTextFile.txt", vbHide
```

Comment: i don't know what you are doing.

Comment: Which part aren't you getting, VBA's `shell` function or Command's `attrib` function? This does exactly what Comintern's code does, it just uses a Command shell instead of an FSO. There's many ways to skin a cat.